# Htmlfile access is denied when using Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been using Server.MapPath("page.aspx") for quite a long time, but it is just now that I faced this problem.

Basically here is my code

`Session.Clear();

 ShowLoggedOffControl(); //A function that setup bunch of controls visibility

 OnUserLoggedOut(new EventArgs());

 Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/Default.aspx"));`

The error would be `htmlfile:access is denied` at javascript execution. However when I removed Server.MapPath so that it became like this `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");`, things work normally.

What did I do wrong? Why, how and when can I use Server.MapPath?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server.MapPath gets the physical path to the file on the hard disk, whereas Response.Redirect expects a URL.

If for some reason you need to get the full URL, you can use this:

```
String.Format("http://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Host, Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Server.MapPath` maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server. So in your example it would end up redirecting to something like this:

```
c:\Projects\MyWebsite\Default.aspx
```

which is probably not what you want.

`Response.Redirect` on the other hand will resolve the '~' to the relative path root for you and resolve to something like this:

```
/MyVirtualDirectory/Default.aspx
```

As for when you would want to use `Server.MapPath`, you would use it if you wanted to actually find the file on the server and do something such as:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/MyTextFile.txt"));
// Do something here with values found
```